# My string comparisons always evaluate to true

Tags: bash

I'm not entirely sure why, but when comparing strings using `if`, the comparison doesn't evaluate properly.

I've tried simplifying the script to a very basic string comparison test

```
\#!/bin/sh

if [ "blah"="hello" ]; then
  echo "blah"
fi

if [ "hello"="hello" ]; then
  echo "hello"
fi
```

I'm expecting a single line output: `hello`.

What I get is:

```
blah
hello
```

Comment: You need spaces around those `=` (otherwise the whole `"blah"="hello"` is parsed as a single string that's equals to `blah=hello`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This command:

```
[ "blah"="hello" ]
```

runs `[` with the arguments `blah=hello` and `]`; so the conditional expression is the single string `blah=hello`, which is true (because it's a non-empty string), so the command returns success, and the code in the `if`-block is run.

What you meant to write was:

```
[ blah = hello ]
```

which passes `blah`, `=`, and `hello` as three separate arguments, and which tests whether `blah` and `hello` are equal. Since they're not, the command returns failure, and the code in the `if`-block is not run.

---

More broadly — you seem to be misunderstanding Bash's `"..."` notation. You're probably taking the double-quotes to indicate the start and end of a string (as in various other languages), but what they really do is "escape" various special characters that would otherwise have specific meanings. Since `blah` doesn't contain any special characters, `"blah"` and `blah` are the same thing.